# ASP.Net Progress Bar Help?

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar

Just wondering if anyone knows of any libraries or decent code that is available for a multi purpose progress bar with an ASP.Net web app? I basically need a progress bar that has one bar, for example of 50%, and then another net to it or on top of it etc that shows 30%?

If anyone could help that would be brilliant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you asking about the Individual item progress along with the Whole uploading progress bar is that so ??

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

### jQuery.UI ProgressBar Widget

**http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/jqueryui_progressbar_widget.html**

**http://www.mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=jQuery.UI+ProgressBar+Widget&Filter=jQuery**

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to use that progressbar? If it is to show how far some server-side processing is completed, that can be a problem.
While you are processing a request, you can't update the screen of the browser, the way you can in a winform application. You would have to move that processing to a separate thread and periodically query how far it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onsubmit = function () {
            if (Page_IsValid) {
                var UpdateProgress1 = $find("<%= UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>");
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            UpdateProgress1.set_visible(true);
        }, 100);
    }
        }
</script>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.modal1
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
}
.center1
{
     position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
    margin: 300px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
}
.center1 img
{
    height: 52px;
    width: 128px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>


<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
     </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelDivEdit">
            <ProgressTemplate>          
                 <div class="modal1"  align="center">
            <div class="center1"  align="center">
                <img src="Images/loader.gif" alt=""  />
                </div>
            </div>             
            </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePaneldivAdd" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

 </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBtnSave" />
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBtnCancel" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), Also, you didn't provide any explanation of your code, can you do it please ?